# Can't accurately calculate averages for box blur implementation

Tags: arrays, c

So... I'm trying to do an implementation of a "box blur" and I tried running a test with a integers matrix. I calculated it manually and I tried to automate it, but when I ran the code the averages seemed to be very inaccurate.

```
/* Reasoning behind it
[+i -j][+i j][+i +j]
[ i -j][ i j][ i +j]
[-1 -j][-i j][-i +j]

This is the box, and obviously there has to be
approximately nine cases. One for each corner,
one for each side and one for the center i's. */
```

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int i, j, width, height;
float avg;
int first_corner(int a[i][j]);
int second_corner(int a[i][j]);
int third_corner(int a[i][j]);
int fourth_corner(int a[i][j]);
int left_side(int a[i][j]);
int right_side(int a[i][j]);
int center(int a[i][j]);
int LOOP(int a[i][j]);

int main(void)
{

    int a[3][4] = {
        {1,5,3,4},
        {4,3,6,7},
        {7,1,9,8}
    };

    // Calculating width and height
    width = sizeof(a[0])/sizeof(int);
    height = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
    printf("%d", LOOP(a));
    // Manually calculating average
    printf("\n%d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d",
    (1+5+4+3)/4, (1+5+3+4+3+6)/6, (5+3+4+3+6+7)/6,
    (4+3+6+7)/4, (1+5+4+3+7+1)/6, (1+5+3+4+3+6+7+1+9)/9,
    (5+3+4+3+6+7+1+9+8)/9, (3+4+6+7+9+8)/6, (4+3+7+1)/4,
    (4+3+6+7+1+9)/6, (3+6+7+1+9+8)/6, (6+7+9+8)/4);
}

// intentar pasarles COLORES como parámetros

int first_corner(int a[i][j])
{
    avg = round((a[i][j]+a[i][j+1]+a[i-1][j]+a[i-1][j+1]) / 4);
    printf("%.f, ", avg);
    return avg;
}

int second_corner(int a[i][j])
{
    avg = round((a[i][j]+a[i-1][j]+a[i-1][j-1]+a[i][j-1]) / 4);
    printf("%.f, ", avg);
    return avg;
}

int third_corner(int a[i][j])
{
    avg = round((a[i][j]+a[i+1][j]+a[i+1][j+1]+a[i][j+1]) / 4);
    printf("%.f, ", avg);
    return avg;
}

int fourth_corner(int a[i][j])
{
    avg = round((a[i][j-1]+a[i+1][j-1]+a[i+1][j]+a[i][j]) / 4);
    printf("%.f\n", avg);
    return avg;
}

int left_side(int a[i][j])
{
    avg = round((a[i][j]+a[i+1][j]+a[i+1][j+1]+a[i][j+1]+a[i-1][j+1]+a[i-1][j]) / 6);
    printf("%.f ", avg);
    return avg;
}

int right_side(int a[i][j])
{
    avg = round((a[i][j]+a[i+1][j]+a[i+1][j-1]+a[i][j-1]+a[i-1][j-1]+a[i-1][j]) / 6);
    printf("%.f, ", avg);
    return avg;
}

int lowerside(int a[i][j])
{
    avg = round((a[i][j]+a[i][j+1]+a[i-1][j+1]+a[i-1][j]+a[i-1][j-1]+a[i][j-1]) / 6);
    printf("%.f, ", avg);
    return avg;
}

int upperside(int a[i][j])
{
    avg = round((a[i][j]+a[i+1][j]+a[i+1][j+1]+a[i][j+1]+a[i][j-1]+a[i+1][j-1]) / 6);
    printf("%.f, ", avg);
    return avg;
}

int center(int a[i][j])
{
    avg = round((a[i][j]+a[i+1][j]+a[i+1][j+1]+a[i][j+1]+a[i-1][j+1]+a[i-1][j]+a[i-1][j-1]+a[i][j-1]+a[i+1][j+1]) / 9);
    printf("%.f, ", avg);
    return avg;
}

int LOOP(int a[i][j])
{
    for (i = 0;  i < height; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            if (i == 0 && j == 0)
            {
                first_corner(a);
            }
            else if (i == 0 && j == width-1)
            {
                second_corner(a);
            }
            else if (i == height-1 && j == 0)
            {
                third_corner(a);
            }
            else if (i == height-1 && j == width-1)
            {
                fourth_corner(a);
            }
            else if ((i == 0 && i < height-1) && (j == 0))
            {
                left_side(a);
            }
            else if ((i > 0 && i < height-1) && (j == width-1))
            {
                right_side(a);
            }
            else if ((i == 0) && (j > 0 && j < width-1))
            {
                upperside(a);
            }
            else if ((i == height-1) && (j > 0 && j < width-1))
            {
                lowerside(a);
            }
            else
            {
                center(a);
            }
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

The output is:

```
~/ $ ./test
3, 3, 3, 8193, 7284, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 1049988
1
3, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 5, 5, 7~/ $
```

I actually don't know if my math is wrong, or if I should tackle the problem from a different approach (which I don't know if it's possible)

Comment: You probably need to use floating point, i.e. divide by 4.0 instead of 4.

Comment: @SvenNilsson I don't think I needed to do that since dividing a float by an integer (to my understanding) makes the integer get treated as a float. I did, nonetheless change it. This is the output: `3, 4, 4, 8193, 7283, 4, 5, 4, 3, 4, 5, 1050004
1
3, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 5, 5, 7~/ $ `

Comment: Well, in this case for example "avg = round((a[i][j]+a[i][j+1]+a[i-1][j]+a[i-1][j+1]) / 4);" you need 4.0 because a is integer matrix and int divided by int is int.

Comment: @MOehm I'm not using bitmaps for now, this failed test was done using the matrix declared in the main function. That might be the case, actually. But I think I made sure to double and triple check the sums in the functions to prevent that from happening :(

Comment: Well, you are not doing yourself a favour by separating the conditions for the corners and edges from the actuall summing in the source file. For example, `first_corner` is called when `i == 0 && j == 0`, yet you access `a[i - 1][j]`, which is out of bounds. That's undefined behaviour; the program could crash, but here it just gives you an unreasonable number.

Comment: Welcome! Please don't make live updates to the posted code in response to fault-finding.

Comment: In a [recent question about the Game of Life](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65159086/game-of-life-does-weird-things-and-i-dont-know-whats-wrong/65159522#65159522), where you count live neighbouring cells, there is a much cleaner way of dealing with the corners and edges, which checks whether a cell is valid inside the inner loop.