# Game Of Life does weird things and I don't know whats wrong

Tags: c, conways-game-of-life

So for an assignment I have to code the game of life in C.
My problem is, that it calculates the next generation wrong but I have no clue why.

I defined my game struct

```
typedef struct gameStruct {
    int width;
    int height;
    char* field;
} Game;
```

For the update I create an temporary array to store the cell states, then iterate over every cell from the actual field. I check the 8 cells next to the current one, check if it's an actual valid neighbor, then get the state of the neighbor cell. After all 8 cells have been checked I set the state for the cell in the temp array. After all cells have been calculated I set field[i] to temp[i].

```
void update() {
    char* newTemp;  
    newTemp = malloc(sizeof(char) * game.width * game.height);

    for (int y = 0; y < game.height; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < game.width; x++) {

            int Index = y * game.width + x;
            int alive_n = 0;
            int dead_n = 0;
            int invalid_n = 0;

            for (int yOff = -1; yOff <= 1; yOff++) {
                for (int xOff = -1; xOff <= 1; xOff++) {
                    if ((xOff == 0 && yOff == 0) || xOff + x < 0 || yOff + y < 0 || x + xOff >= game.width || y + yOff >= game.height) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    else {
                        int newIndex = (y + yOff) * game.width + (x + xOff);
                        switch (game.field[newIndex]) {
                            case '*': alive_n++; break;
                            case ' ': dead_n++; break;
                        default: invalid_n++; break;
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
            }

            char next_state = ' ';
            if (alive_n == 2 || alive_n == 3) {
                next_state = '*';
            }
            else if (alive_n == 0 && dead_n == 3) {
                next_state = '*';
            }
            newTemp[Index] = next_state;        
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < game.width * game.height; i++){
            game.field[i] = newTemp[i];
    }
    free(newTemp);
}
```

So basically it just does weird stuff that seems totally random.
Here is what my result looks compared to an online game of life using the same configuration:

[image: left: my version | right : https://www.dcode.fr/game-of-life]

Game Of Life I used for comparison: https://www.dcode.fr/game-of-life

I have no more ideas what the problem could be. Maybe anyone here can help me spot the mistake? Thanks!

Comment: Your starting configuration doesn't look like two 2x2 squares.

Comment: Oof, yes I cut the first generation off accidentally. But it was the same start config

Comment: What is `newIndex`? I can't find that anywhere. That seems off.

Comment: newIndex is the index of the neighbor cell. I should change the name though. I just saw I forgot to include this line here 
`int newIndex = (y + yOff) * game.width + (x + xOff);`

Comment: Your condition must take into account the state of the current (centre) cell, but you don't do that. If it is currently alive, it will survive if it has two or three neighbours; if it is currently dead, if will remain dead unless it has three neighbours.

Comment: @lulZghost It should be updated in the loop shouldn't it? It's value is the same for the entire `update` call.

Comment: It's also not clear where `newIndex` is calculated from the offset position.

Comment: @MOehm Ahh, can't believe I missed that as well.

Comment: @MOehm I re-added the line. I have it in my project but I deleted some comments to make it cleaner here and removed that line. 
`newIndex = (y + yOff) * game.width + (x + xOff);`

Comment: You forgot to define and compute `int newIndex` from the location and offsets. You don't take into account the current state. And there is no need to count dead neighbours - only live cells are considered for the next generation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is how you update the cells. The rules are:

- a live cell dies if it doesn't have 2 or 3 live neighboure;
- a dead cell comes alive if it has 3 live neighbours.

That means that you must consider the current state of the cell to determine its next state, but your code doesn't do that. (It also means that it is enough to count the live neighbours.)

With the rules above, your update code should look like this:

```
        char next_state = field[Index];
        
        if (next_state == '*') {
            if (alive_n != 2 && alive_n != 3) next_state = ' ';
        } else {
            if (alive_n == 3) next_state = '*';
        }
        
        newTemp[Index] = next_state;
```